# How to know if everything was appended to csv?

Tags: java, csv

Here is my code:

```
public static void writeDataToCSV(CustomObjectData customObjectData, int pageCounter) {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        int elementCounter = 0;
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        String tmp = "";

        // System.out.println("Size of customobjectdata elements, should be 1000: 
"+customObjectData.elements.size());

        for (CustomObjectDataElements x : customObjectData.elements) {
            for (FieldValue y : x.fieldValues) {
                values.add(y.value);
            }
            for (String element : values) {
                tmp += element + ";";
            }

            writer.append(tmp.substring(0, tmp.length() - 1) + "\r\n");
            // count elements written into file to track in case of failure
            elementCounter++;
            if (elementCounter % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");

            FileWriter out = new FileWriter("data\\resumeat.txt");
            System.out.print(elementCounter+pageCounter*1000+"");
            out.write(elementCounter+pageCounter*1000+"");
            out.close();
            values.clear();
            tmp = "";
        }
        System.out.println("Records: "+pageCounter*1000+" - "+ 
((pageCounter+1)*1000-1) +" written to csv.");
        // System.out.println("Headers: "+CSVHeaders+" Values: "+CSVValues);

        System.out.print(".");

        if (i >= 99) {
            System.out.println("");
            i = -1;
        }

        i++;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

It is simple method which is appending records to csv. Unfortunately I need to keep track on every record which was imported so then if program crashes I can start from that record.

I tried it by saving number of element, which was appended last, to txt file.

BUT, in txt file I have written e.g. 2000 and in csv is just 1987 records. That means that if I use writer.append it is not executed immediately. Even if my counter is after that appending. It looks like program does not wait until it is appended. Can I check it somehow if it was already appended or any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), it does what its name suggests: I uses a buffer. If at a certain point in time you want to be sure all data from that buffer is written out, you have to issue a call to `writer.flush` (unless you already closed `writer`).

Comment: I think you are right, very soon I will accept the answer, thanks.